# matching input to an external file

Tags: php

I have designed a registration page and I now need to take the input from the login page and match it to an external file. (I understand MySQL is easier, but this is for a project and I *cannot* use MySQL at all.)

I have on the external file:

```
fname, sname, username, password, e-mail
```

I need to verify the username and password on my txt file. My login pages looks like this:

```
<form action="logon.php" method="POST">
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></p>
    <p>Password:  <input type="password" name="password"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<a href="register.php">Register Here</a>
<?php               
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$arrangefile = preg_split( '/\n/' , $contents );
$found = false;

foreach ( $arrangefile as $items ) {
   $data = explode ( ',' , $items );
}
} ?>
```

Comment: Quick tip, instead of using that ugly `preg_split()`, you can do `$arrangefile = file($file);` and omit the `preg_split()` and `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 0):

Well...aside from having to say that it's an odd idea to do it like that, you could replace `file_get_contents()` with `file()`. It yields an array with one line of the file at a time. That would make parsing a whole lot easier. In your `foreach` you need to tokenize the line and extract the username and password. Then you can match them.

It might look like this:

```
<?php               
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$contents = file($file);
$found = false;

foreach ($file as $line) {
   $data = explode(', ', $line);
   if (($username === $data[2]) && ($password === $data[3])) {
      $found = true;
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<form action="logon.php" method="POST">
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></p>
    <p>Password:  <input type="password" name="password"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<a href="register.php">Register Here</a>
<?php               
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$lines = file ($file);
$found = false;

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = str_replace (' ', '', $line);
    $cols = explode (',', $line);

    $_username = $cols[2];
    $_password = $cols[3];

    if ($username == $_username && $password == $_password) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Do something with $found
if ($found) {
    // yay
}
else {
    // aww :(
}
?>
```

EDIT:
A little bit more explanation. `file()` puts all the lines of the file into an `array()`. Each element represents a line in the file. You said you have the data in `a, b, c` format. You use `str_replace()` to remove all spaces to make the `explode()` easier. Then its just a matter of `explode()`ing the data and comparing the results.

Hope this helps.